# How can I make a zip file of a directory except specific folder of it?

Tags: command-line, zip

Here is my current command:

```
zip -r compressed_filename.zip path/foldername
```

But there is lots of images into a folder named `img` in there `path/foldername`. So I want to make a file zip of `path/foldername` directory except `img` folder which is into it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Always it is good idea to have a look on manpage of the command you want to use. Run `man zip` and search for exclude by pressing `/` and `n` for searching forward, you will be taking to the right place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`zip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) command has an `--exclude` (or `-x`) flag to exclude some files:

```
zip -r --exclude 'img/' compressed_filename.zip path/foldername
```

Adjust the paths if necessary.

---

You can also use the [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command to list all the files to be included and pass them to the `zip` command.

```
find path/foldername -name 'img' -prune -o -exec zip compressed_filename.zip {} +
```

This will search the `path/foldername` for all files (and folders). If it finds `img`, it stops processing it (`-prune`). All other (`-o`) found items will be (together, because of `+` at the end) passed to the `zip` invocation.